# .net: how to optimize this code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, optimization, refactoring

Please help me optimize/ refactor this code.....

```
private sub test
        Call PopulateColorsWithMasterIdentity(Colors, Id)
        Call PopulatePartsWithMasterIdentity(Parts, Id)
        Call PopulateSaloonsWithMasterIdentity(Saloons, Id)
End sub

Private Sub PopulateColorsWithMasterIdentity(ByRef MyList As List(Of entclsCriticalPartSetColor), ByVal Id As Integer)

    For index As Byte = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        MyList.Item(index).CriticalPartsSetId = Id
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulatePartsWithMasterIdentity(ByRef MyList As List(Of entclsCriticalPartSetPart), ByVal Id As Integer)

    For index As Byte = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        MyList.Item(index).CriticalPartsSetId = Id
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateSaloonsWithMasterIdentity(ByRef MyList As List(Of entclsCriticalPartSetSaloon), ByVal Id As Integer)

    For index As Byte = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        MyList.Item(index).CriticalPartsSetId = Id
    Next
End Sub
```

****EDIT****

Actually, Is it possible to use "Polymorphism"? I mean, instead of having 3 different parts of populateXXXWithMasterIdentity, can I have one PopulateListWithMasterIdentity like this one:

```
Private Sub PopulateListWithMasterIdentity(MyList As IList(Of entclsCriticalPartsBase), Id As Integer)
    .....
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: What problem is this code trying to solve? What is your motivation for refactoring it?

Comment: @Sapph, I just edited my post: How can I have a single PopulateXXX instead of 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare an interface that contains the property `CriticalPartsSetId` which is common to all three types that you use:

```
Public Interface IHasCriticalPartsSetId
    Property CriticalPartsSetId As Integer
End Interface
```

Make sure that your three different types implement this interface.

Next, write one single method that updates the `CriticalPartsSetId` property:

```
Sub PopulateId(xs As IEnumerable(Of IHasCriticalPartsSetId), id As Integer)
    For Each x in xs
        x.CriticalPartsSetId = id
    Next
End Sub
```

Right now I'm not quite sure whether `IEnumerable(Of IHasCriticalPartsSetId)` will work as expected, or if you'll indeed need to use a generic type parameter constraint, as shown in Marc Gravell's answer — in VB.NET this would be: `IEnumerable(Of T As IHasCriticalPartsSetId)`.

Note also another completely unrelated optimization: Getting rid of a `For` loop with a `Byte` counter. Using a `For Each` loop makes your code easier to read. (And using a `Byte`-typed counter variable might actually give you worse performance than using an `Integer`-typed variable, since (IIRC) the `CLR` expands `Byte`-sized values to `Integer`-sized values when it puts them on its internal execution stack.)

Comment: @staks, IEnumerable or IList? All 3 Subs have 1 parameter as a generic list.

Comment: *@odiseh*, I chose `IEnumerable` on purpose: It's the less-"demanding" type of the two, and it's actually sufficient for what the method does. That is, `IEnumerable` requires less from the caller than `IList` does, and the method -- more specifically, the `For Each` loop -- requires only an `IEnumerable`, nothing more. So, by choosing `IEnumerable`, the method is more versatile than if one had chosen `IList`.

Comment: *@odiseh*: A slightly off-topic P.S. to the above comment: What I was talking about is related to the idea of *"require less (from 'in'-bound parameters), ensure more (through the 'out'-bound return type)"* that you find with subtyping and covariance/contravariance.

Comment: @Staks: I did what you pointed out but there is an error indicating that "Unable to cast ......" I wrote this: Private Sub PopulateId(Byval MyList As IEnumerable(Of entBase), Byval Id As Integer) .......End Sub and call it in this way: CType(Colors, IEnumerable(Of entclsBase)), Id)  What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can’t really optimize this code but you can make it a bit more concise because the `Item` property call is completely redundant.

Furthermore, please don’t use the `Byte` type for the index variable, that doesn’t make any sense, even if the lists never have more than 255 elements. Always use `Integer` here (or let the compiler infer your type by using `Option Infer On`).

Instead, write the loops as follows:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
    MyList(index).CriticalPartsSetId = Id
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

In the updates you are mutating every object; so it can't be better than O(n), which it is already. No optimisation is necessary. As a refactor, I'd take away the `ByRef` - you aren't using it. You might also consider a common base-class or interface, then all 3 could share a single generic method. In c# terms:

```
interface IFoo {
    int CriticalPartsSetId {get;set;}
}
public static void UpdateCriticalPartsSetId<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> items, int criticalPartsSetId)
    where T : IFoo
{
     foreach(var item in items)
        item.CriticalPartsSetId = criticalPartsSetId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your polymorphism question, yes you could. But you don't really need to. All three of these classes share a common property (CriticalPartsSetId), so you could put that on a base class and let all of them inherit it. Polymorphism would let you change something about that on the subclass, but in this case that isn't necessary since CriticalPartsSetId does the same thing.

I kind of wonder though, are the three lists you have here all parts of the same thing? Maybe it'd make more sense to do something like this:

```
Public Class CriticalPartsSet

    Public Property SetId as Integer
    Public Property SetColors as List(of entclsCriticalPartSetColor)
    Public Property SetParts as List(of entclsCriticalPartSetPart)
    Public Property SetSaloons as List(of entclsCriticalPartSetSaloon)

End Class
```

If you do that, the setId is part of the set itself and changing it is a single operation instead of an iteration on three lists. You can also pass around the entire set and everything about it as a single parameter to methods that need it, which is handy. :)

(Finally, as others as mentioned you should remove the ByRef and use ByVal. ByRef lets you replace the list with an entirely different list and have the caller get the new list, which is NOT the intended behaviour here. You can modify things inside the list with ByVal, and there's less chance for unintended oddness later.)